# Model not appearing, animating

Tags: modeling, rendering, animation

The model in the lower right animates when I[image] hit play and won't appear in Render Image. I don't want the model to animate and don't know how to turn it off. All other models appear just fine and do not animate when I hit play.

Comment: Look into the Outliner and see if you've not assigned an animation to your armature? If yes, right click and Clear Animation Data

Comment: Oh, thanks for your help!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the *Outliner* and see if you've not assigned an animation to your armature. If so, right click and *Clear Animation Data*.